# Form with two tables as source

Tags: atk4

I have two tables master and detail.

When I add a new record to master, after that I need to add records to the detail table.

Is it possible to have a form with tow "setSource()" methods ? Or do I have to make first one form, and then add a second with the ID of the first as parameter ??

Which can be the best approach ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can actually call form's setModel() several times in atk4.2 and it will import fields from appropriate model and will save them simultaneously within the same sql transaction.

Comment: wow, Impressed. I'm going to test it with 4.2 . I'm using 4.1.4 Thanks